# Culinary heritage?(meaning)

Tags: phrase-meaning

While watching 'Bizarre Foods,' on TFC channel, I came across something called **culinary heritage.**

I wonder what does it mean.

Is this a trademark cuisine that is passed down from generation to generation? I'm not sure...

Comment: Where did you hear this phrase? Please [provide more context](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1084/so-you-found-a-sentence-or-phrase-why-you-should-cite-your-source).

Comment: Hello, this is from 'bizzare foods' hope you know this exotic food documentary in TFC channel or something. Anyway, it was spoken by a non-native english speaker, and I thought that it can be useful to add this to my english vocabulary to be more accurate especially when I needed to more descriptive. Is it ok now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You nailed it!

It means the recipes or dishes that our forefathers and grandparents used to cook/make. They also carry *a cultural value,* at least in India.

---

There are heritage family recipes. I had recently discussed this in one of my lectures. In my country, there are many special dishes along with the traditions are vanishing into the thin air. We are worried about it.

Comment: Thx man, that 'cultural value' is what I was lacking.

Comment: You are welcome @JohnArvin! Surprisingly, most of Indian foods are *linked* with cultures and/or festivals!